# How to fix lack of color contrast in VSCode selection tool?

Tags: visual-studio-code, ide

[image]

In the image I have the letters "dg" highlighted in VSCode. VSCode then higlights the rest of string with a ever-so-slightly lighter color.

This is driving me insane. It's really hard to tell what I actually have selected when it does this.

What is the variable I need to change in the theme to fix this? Or is this even fixable? I can't find a particular attribute to adjust that changes that weird 'slightly lighter than the color you are using to highlight color.'

I've tried `editor.selectionBackground` and `editor.selectionHighlightBackground` but neither appear to address the issue.

I'd be happy if I could even just add a border to my selected text, but I can't find a variable for that either (Though there appears to be a border option for 'higlighting similar items'.)

Comment: do you have the same behavior when choosing another theme, if not customize a theme color for a particular theme, see mark answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for this `Theme Color`:

```
    "editor.wordHighlightBackground": "#fff0",
```

It is highlighting the `word` around the cursor/selection.  That being the `word` as defined by your language server.

I set it to be transparent in the above `colorCustomization` by giving it the 4th hex value for opacity.

See [VS Code Theme Color reference](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/theme-color#editor-colors).

Comment: it should be customized for a particular theme

Comment: Thanks...this helps but I think I realize the issue...you can't separate the 'selected' color from the 'entire word' color beacuse the selected color is merely a transparency of the other. 

It seems like a poorly through out feature.